# Catching exception from DAO to the first class calling method,

Tags: java, exception, rmi

The architecture of my application is like this:

> Main classe -> ServiceBean -> Manager -> DAO.

I am throwing an exception in my DAO:

```
catch (HibernateException he) {
        throw new RemuRuntimeLoggableException(he, RuntimeLoggableException.HIBERNATE_UNKNOWN);
    }
```

Then in Manager I catch the exception as below:

```
catch (RuntimeLoggableException e) {
                            log.info(e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            throw new RuntimeLoggableException(e, RuntimeLoggableException.HIBERNATE_UNKNOWN);
```

And in my ServiceBean, I have this:

```
catch (RuntimeLoggableException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RemoteException();
```

In my main class, I have caught the exception like this:

```
catch (RemoteException e) {
        log.info(prefixeLog + " Error");
        log.info(e.getMessage());
```

I also have an interface Service.java. ServiceBean implements this interface and the method concerned here is declared as below in the interface, Service.java:

```
 public void calculate( boolean flag )
  throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
```

The problem I am getting is that the exception RemoteException from the ServiceBean, is not caught in the main class.  And I can't modify the interface Service.java as it is automatically generated by XDoclet.  Any idea of how to do this please?

In my Service.java, the method is declared like this:

```
  public void calculate( boolean flag )
  throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
```

And in my class it is declared as below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws RuntimeLoggableException {
 try {
        log.info("Start" + prefixeLog);
        serviceBean.calculate(true);
        log.info("End" + prefixeLog);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        log.info(prefixeLog + " Error");
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        InitFramework.stopFramework(FrameworkFacade.BATCH);
        System.exit(retour);
    }
}
```

And in my serviceBean:

```
 public void calculate(boolean flagExclurePlansPerimes) throws RemoteException {
```

Comment: Is it possible that `RemoteException` has multiple implementations on multiple libraries? try in the main to have: `catch (java.rmi.RemoteException ex) { ... }`

Comment: @AvihooMamka: Your solution does not work either.  The main class and the other classes are on different projects. I have added some more explanation in my question.  Can you check it please?

Comment: if this is still a problem, can you please add the log messages that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the message of the `RemoteException` but you are thrown a `RemoteException` that is constructed without a message.

Comment: I have modified my code to throw a RemoteException with a message but still this does not work.  The main class and the other classes are in two different projects.